# Include a '%' in an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How can I include a percent symbol (%) in my NSString?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading (%1.0%)",  percentage]
```

The above code does not include the last percent in the string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Carl is right about the escaping, but it alone won't work with the code you have given. You are missing a format specifier after the first percentage sign. Given `percentage` is a double, try:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading (%.1f %%)",  percentage];
```

Note the `%.1f`, for formatting a double with one decimal. This gives `45.5 %`. Use `%.f` for no decimals.

Also see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Thanks very much -- can't believe that I was leaving out the format specifier.  Looking at the code for far too long yesterday.

Answer (score 11):

Use `%%` to escape the percent sign.

Comment: @TomH, then you still have something wrong with your code - check out @Mads answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading (%g%%)",  percentage];
```